# Android application structure: Scheduled Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm having trouble with my app. What I want is:

MainActivity launches & creates a scheduled thread which periodically checks whether the WiFi service is enabled. If it IS, go to a new activity. If it ISN'T then launch a warning & take the user to the WiFi settings page.

When the user comes back to the Main Activity, the MainActivity code will now sense the WiFi service is enabled & send them to the second activity.

I have this working. Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    ScheduledExecutorService oScheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    try
    {
        oScheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate({RUNNABLE HERE}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("(MainActivity) Caught Exception here. #1");
        System.out.println("(MainActivity) Error: " + e.getMessage() + " Cause: " + e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    // Assign WifiManager to System service
    oWiFiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        // Create Runnable
        oWiFiUpdater = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                // If we should show WiFi Disabled
                if (shouldShowWiFiAlert())
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            launchWiFiDisabledAlert();
                        }
                        });
                }

                        Intent oAPListIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APList.class);
                        startActivity(oAPListIntent);
            }
        }
};
```

However when we are on the second activity, the first thread is still running. I thought that when the Activity is removed from View, all threads cease running??

I want the executor to only run when the Activity is viewable! Any ideas!?

EDIT: Answer thanks to inspiration from njzk2

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    createWiFiAlertDialog();

    boolean bWiFiEnabling = wifiEnabling();
    while (bWiFiEnabling)
    {
        try
        {
            doSyncedWait(500);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("(MainActivity) Exception caught waiting. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        bWiFiEnabling = wifiEnabling();
    }
    boolean bWiFiEnabled = wifiReady();
    if (!bWiFiEnabled)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog oAlertDialog = m_oAlertDialog;
                oAlertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Intent oIntent = new Intent(this,APList.class);
        startActivity(oIntent);
    }
}

private boolean wifiEnabling()
{
    WifiManager oWiFiManager = m_oWiFiManager;
    if (oWiFiManager == null) return false;

    if (oWiFiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) return true;
    return false;
}

private boolean wifiReady()
{
    WifiManager oWiFiManager = m_oWiFiManager;
    if (oWiFiManager == null) return false;

    // If the WiFi state is anything other than enabled, then wait.
    if (oWiFiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so it periodically send the user to the wifi settings page ? I don't quite understand that. Why not simply test the wifi status in the onResume of your activity, and offer the user to either leave or go to the wifi settings if required ?

Comment: Ahh brilliant! Its amazing what a different take on things can have! That & the fact that I'm a complete newbie with Android. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you give your runnable a reference to the activity, and set a boolean to `true` in `onResume()` and `false` in `onPause()`, you should be able to reference the boolean from your runnable and then use a if statement to only run if the boolean is set to true.